# Elastic search problem with node disk size

Tags: elasticsearch

I try update data in elastic search index.

Count of documents is always same, but shard size on disk is always grow.

After "Force merge"

```
/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true
```

Shard size come back to normal, but this operation make index "read only".

Is it any solution to auto merge data without making index "read only"?

Answer (score 0):

Force merge can be schedule automatic by ES **ConcurrentMergeScheduler**,  force merge will make search slowly, you can do it at midnight, using SSD will be quickly.  This's some index config affect merge:

1. index.merge.policy.expunge_deletes_allowed
2. index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count
3. index.refresh_interval   (Increase this value make less segments)